# ID (auto-increment) muito elevado pode ser prejudicial?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, auto-incremento

Tenho uma tabela que tem uma rotatividade bem alta de informações, ou seja, muitos registros entram e muitos saem também. Com isso o ID (auto-increment) fica bem mais alto que o valor de dados existentes na tabela.

Por exemplo, a tabela está com 530 registros e o ID (auto-increment) está em 1250, e esses números tendem a aumentar de maneira relativamente rápida.

Gostaria de saber se isso pode causar alguma lentidão ou pode ser ruim de alguma maneira para meu banco de dados e minha aplicação. Se causa algum problema, o que posso fazer para melhorar isso?

Obs: Não sei se muda em algo, mas os IDs dessa tabela são chaves estrangeiras em outras tabelas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No postgres o campo auto-increment é chamado de sequence, um id com número elevado não causa lentidão em uma consulta, o problema que pode acontecer é esse campo (int talvez) chegue rapidamente ao seu limite nesse caso seria necessário trocar por um tipo de capacidade maior como bigint.

Um fato curioso que acontece a um tempo atrás foi o contador de vizualizações do youtube estourar após isso, começou a aparecer um número negativo de views no video do psy.

Trecho retirado de [Como 'Gangnam Style' estourou o contador do YouTube](http://www.bbc.com/portuguese/noticias/2014/12/141204_youtube_psy_gangnam_style_lgb)

> O contador do YouTube até agora utilizava um marcador de 32-bit, unidade que representa os dados na arquitetura computacional.
>
> Isso significa que o número máximo de visitas que poderiam ser registradas era de 2.147.483.647.

Comment: entendi, e o número máximo que minha sequence sendo um campo int pode chegar é 2.147.483.647? Foi o que achei em uma pesquisa.